# How to change text color in python-pptx?

Tags: python, powerpoint, python-pptx

Currently this is my code:

```
from pptx import Presentation
from pptx.util import Pt

f = open(r'template.pptx', 'rb')
prs = Presentation(f)
f.close()

slide = prs.slides.add_slide(prs.slide_masters[0].slide_layouts[1])

title = slide.placeholders[10]
title.text = "REPORT"

prs.save('test.pptx')
```

How do I format the 'REPORT' title text, to be yellow and bold?

Comment: Could you give us the `template.pptx` so we can try your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access the font properties using `title.font`:

```
from pptx.dml.color import RGBColor # add this import to the top of the file

title.font.bold = True
title.font.color.rgb = RGBColor(0xFF, 0xFF, 0x00)
```

Comment: What worked for me was: ```title.text_frame.paragraphs[0].font.color.rgb = RGBColor(0xFF, 0xFF, 0x00)```